# superclass method not working as Expected, Why?

Tags: python-3.x, object, inheritance, super, magic-methods

This is my self defined class. But error occurs.

```
>>> class Int(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return super() + other


>>> f = Int(10)
>>> f + 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#110>", line 1, in <module>
    f + 4
  File "<pyshell#108>", line 3, in __add__
    return super() + other
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'super' and 'int'
```

I know replacing `return super() + other` with `return super().__add__(other)` solves the problem. But why doesn't the previous code work. I am confused. Can anyone please explain.

I know `super()` returns a type: `<class 'super'>`. Then why `super.__add__(other)` work and `super() + other` doesn't ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `overload operators` in this case to perform the customized addition. Unlike typical `scalar addition`, python doesn't know how to perform the addition of custom type that you are asking for and hence it complain. There is a good reference available [here](https://stackabuse.com/overloading-functions-and-operators-in-python/#:~:targetText=Python%20supports%20both%20function%20and,the%20scope%20of%20a%20class.) which will help you as a starting point to do further research.